# ¿por que mi codigo c no guarda completo el nombre completo y solo guarda los primera cadena?

Tags: c, linux, windows, unix, programacion-asincrona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podemos observar se supone que guarda la cadena pero cuando lo guarda no parece completo

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbf5J.png): [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es por que usas `scanf`, esto lee la cadena hasta encontrar un espacio, mejor usa `fgets`

Comment: muchas gracias christian

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como funciona el sitio y también obtengas tu primera medalla! también lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Las imágenes mostrando código no son bien recibidas, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/482899/edit) tu pregunta